# Knockout Check Box binding to ajax retrieved value

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to programming in general but especially knockout.  I have a table that is being populated with a foreach binding.  In this table I have a column that I would like to be a checkbox whose checked value is populated from a mysql database value retrieved via ajax.  I understand that the checked binding should be able to take a 0 or 1 and loosely convert to checked and unchecked.

*http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html*

> For checkboxes, KO will set the element to be checked when the
>   parameter value is true, and  unchecked when it is false. If you give
>   a value that isn’t actually boolean, it will be interpreted  loosely.
>   This means that nonzero numbers and non-null objects and non-empty
>   strings will all be  interpreted as true, whereas zero, null,
>   undefined, and empty strings will be interpreted as  false.

So let's say this is my ko.observableArray named parts:

```
{"id":"1","partdes":"asdf","partcost":"1.00","sellcost":"2.00","tax":"1"}
```

And I have this code snippet from my table:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: parts">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: partdes"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: partcost"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: sellcost"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: tax" /></td>

          //And I added this line to get the actual value: 
        <td data-bind="text: tax"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Everything works fine except the checkbox is always checked even when the value is 0.  Why doen't this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> nonzero numbers and non-null objects and non-empty strings will all be
>   interpreted as true

In your case both `"1"` and `"0"` are non-empty  strings, that cast to `true`. 
Your code would work if you had the numeric value of `tax` (`"tax": 1` or `"tax": 0`)

Comment: I believe you are correct here as I have read that ajax passes boolean values as strings.  Any suggestions on how to convert back to boolean once the value comes through?

Comment: > I have read that ajax passes boolean values as strings.

That's not correct. You can pass boolean or numeric or string. I'd suggest checking the back-end code.

If you have no control over the back-end, you can process the data upon receiving on the front-end. Something like: `data.parts.forEach(function (d) { d.tax = (d.tax === '0' ? false : true); });

Comment: Unfortunately I do have control over the back-end, which is the problem.  After doing some research I was able to convert my variable into a boolean in PHP on the backend of my ajax call with _$success=settype($tax, "boolean");_.  This converted $tax to boolean and passed as true / false allowing me to use the call natively and not have to change any of my code on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

I've created [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bmznm/6/) with an example of checked binding.

```
self.parts.push(new part({id: 1, tax: 0}));    -- set as non checked
self.parts.push(new part({id: 2, tax: 1}));    -- set as checked
self.parts.push(new part({id: 3, tax: true})); -- set as checked
```

Comment: Yes I see your example works and I probably should create this type of mapping, and may have to. As of now I am using ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, ViewModel.parts) so this mapping is automatically being passed.  I don't know how to force that value to a boolean or integer.

Comment: I believe as I learn more about knockout this would probably be the better solution.  I chose amakhrov's answer as I didn't have to change any code to implement it.  I will study your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a particular way of dealing with true / false: a statement can be "truthy" or "falsy".
For instance "0" is "truthy", but it is not true. There are two kinds of comparison operators in javascript. If you want to test the equality, you can use "==" or "===" (or "!=" and "!==" for non-equality). The last one means strict equality. You can test it with the following code:

```
var test = "1";
if(test) {
    alert("truthy");
}
if(test == true) {
    alert("truthy");
}
if(test === true) {
    alert("but not true!");
}
```

The first two alerts will be displayed. The last one won't. The string is truthy (it is neither defined nor null), but it is not strictly equal to true.

In your case, Knockout tests for "normal" equality (truthy). Which means that "0" or "1" strings will be both truthy. If your variables were pure integer, 0 would be falsy and strictly equals to false, and 1 would be truthy and equals to true.

So you have to use either booleans or integer in your JSON and that will work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: (tax==0||!tax)?false:true" /></td>
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work for me.  I think based on other answers I would need this to be an integer and not a string for it to work.  I did modify my php on the back end of the ajax call to return true of false (in a string of course).  Could this be modified to reflect a string value instead of an integer?  Forgive my stupid question but I don't really know what you are doing here.